# Unicode characters in bibtex

Tags: linux, debian, latex, unicode, bibtex

I am struggling with unicode chars in bibtex (Debian). I have the following entry in my .bib file:

```
@Book{bjork2009,
author = {Tomas Björk},
title = {Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time},
publishe = {Oxford University Press},
year = {2009}
}
```

and it works fine for `plain` bibliography style, but fails horribly for the more alphanumeric styles (e.g. apa, alpha) - the error reported is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
&lt;argument&gt; \protect \astroncite 
                                {BjÃ¶rk}{2009}
l.3 ...rotect\astroncite{BjÃ¶rk}{2009}]{bjork2009}
```

any ideas how to get it working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bibtex is not really unicode aware. In order to use extended characters, you need to use the standard Tex replacements.

You might however want to use [biblatex](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) for a better management of bibliographic styles; and maybe have a look at [biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/), which aims to become a unicode aware Bibtex replacement.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we didn't have Unicode symbols rendered in the bibliography.

We generate bibliography with `bibtex` and use Texmaker to edit and preview the tex files.

The solution that worked for us was to add the following to our `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me. I'm using TexWorks and compiling with pdfLaTex

Answer (score 0):

This is it! I was exporting my bibliography from Zotero and running into trouble with é, ñ, ç and other non-ascii characters in author's names.
FWIW, if you're using [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/), you shouldn't put this directly in the "Latex Preamble" section of the "Document Settings" menu (`pdflatex` will complain of doubly setting the encoding): the menu option setting the encoding is "Document Settings > Language > Encoding"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).